# Angular8 Router doesn't work for some components - falls back to index

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, frontend, router

i've got some problems with the angular router.
I have a project with a few components: [project hierarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6Jmw.png)
Now I'm able to route from app.component to login.component and from there also to overview.component.
Shortly, routing between these 3 Components works!

But now i added the logbook.component and want to route to this, it always falls back to the app.component
Doesn't matter if i put it into the URL path directly or if i use `router.navigate(['logbook']);` inside a click method.
The url shows that the app tries to route to `/logbook` but then i just see the app.component again...

This is my app-routing.module.ts:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'overview',
    component: OverviewComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'logbook',
    component: LogbookComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

And this is my logbook.component (just added it):

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-logbook',
  templateUrl: './logbook.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./logbook.component.less']
})
export class LogbookComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
}
```

And finally the overview.component, from where i want to route to the logbook.component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-overview',
  templateUrl: './overview.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./overview.component.less']
})
export class OverviewComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }

  currentUser: string;
  isAdmin: boolean = false;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if (!this.loginService.checkLogin()) { // Check if user is logged in
      this.router.navigate(['login']);
    }
    this.checkUserAdmin();
    this.currentUser = localStorage.getItem('user_surname') + ' ' + localStorage.getItem('user_name');
  }

  checkUserAdmin(): void {
    if (!localStorage.getItem('trainer')) {
      return;
    }
    const item: string = localStorage.getItem('trainer');
    if (item === '1') {
      this.isAdmin = true;
    }
  }

  routeMethod(): void { //called on click in html component
    this.router.navigate(['logbook']);
  }
}
```

I hope this question hasn't been answered before, but i couldn't find anything similar on the internet.
Would be great if you could help! Thanks :)

GitLab Repo is open to read at the moment: https://gitlab.com/andreas.rainer5301/fab-lerntagebuch/

Comment: Have you tried to debug your logbook.component.ts? Does the function `checkLogin` return the correct value?

Comment: If you are sure that is not `ngOnInit` redirection call problem, then you have to provide us your Html code, specially with navigation part. If you are not sure, try to debug it (even simple `console.log()` will do the work).

Comment: Yes returns correct value, true when id exists

Comment: What would be a OnInit redirection problem?

Comment: files are available under: https://gitlab.com/andreas.rainer5301/fab-lerntagebuch/

Comment: No i think it can't be a redirection problem, because /logbook stays in the url, as well as with all other components except the 3 which are working...

Comment: Soooo.... did some more debugging and stuff and it came out that the routes are working. i.e. if i put OverviewComponent to the path /logbook all is fine, but if i do the same with my logbookComponent it does show me the app.component insted of the kogbook.component....     Is there something i must do that a Component can be like standalone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your routing is working correctly, but your `app.component.html` is covering up the screen with the "`resetScreen`" class. Remember, `app.component.html` is the root component and is always displayed.

The only reason `overview.component.html` is showing is because it covers up `app.component.html` with "`overview`" class when routed.

You may want to conditionally show the "`resetScreen`" element.

`app.component.html`:

```
<div *ngIf="!isLoggedIn" class="resetScreen">
  <div class="btn_reset" (click)="showLoginScreen()"></div>
  <div class="btn_start" (click)="showLoginScreen()"></div>
</div>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public router: Router, private loginService: LoginService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    if(this.isLoggedIn) {
      this.router.navigate(['overview']);
    }
  }

  showLoginScreen(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['login']);
  }

  get isLoggedIn(): boolean {
    return this.loginService.checkLogin();
  }

}
```

Or maybe move the html element from `app.component.ts` into its own routed component, like the others.

Comment: You're welcome! I was as confused as you until I inspected the html in my browser.